# SUMIF for two worksheets that have account numbers

Tags: excel, match

I have two worksheets with account numbers and an income number.  I'm trying to find a sumif function for if the account number in Column A matches an account in Column B, it will then add the corresponding values together.

**This is the data set:**

[image: http://imgur.com/e0fQPd2]

**This is the answer column I would like:**

[image: http://imgur.com/qxGWz6V]

I've tried a variation of SUMIF and MATCH functions, but I can't figure out how to set multiple columns as ranges.  I am also not sure if I am using the correction functions.

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed you have two sheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` where both **Account Numbers** are in Column A and **Income** in Column B.

Try adding this to cell **C2** and dragging the folmula down for the rest:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A, $A2, Sheet2!$B:$B) + $B2
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! It sort of worked but I figured out the problem.  Instead of only putting $A2, I had to put A:A.  After that worked like a charm!  Thanks very much!!!

Comment: I'm glad I helped but don't know why that helped. Could you share your formula?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **vlookup** on any sheet. This will get income from other sheet if the account number matches and then using if condition you can add both the income columns.
Kindly refer to below image.

[image]

**OUPTUT**

[image]